# Selecting the closest h2 heading to a cloned element

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a pizza form where the user can select a pizza and then add another pizza to the the order if they wish (by cloning the original pizza form). The cost of each pizza appears in an h2 heading next to the form.

**The problem**: If the user selects a pizza they want and then clicks the Add Pizza button, the price from the previous pizza is automatically placed into the new h2 heading (even though the user hasn't yet selected a second pizza).

How do I remove the text in the newly cloned h2 heading?

HTML:

```
   <div id="pizzaForm">
        <fieldset>
            <form class="pure-form">
            <legend>Pizza</legend>
            <label><b>Pizza Type: &nbsp;</b></label>
            <select id="pizza">
                <option name="margarita">Margarita</option>
                <option name="deep-pan">Deep Pan</option>
                <option name="stuffed-crust">Stuffed Crust</option>
            </select>
                <span style="float:right">
                <label><b>Pizza Size: &nbsp;</b></label>
                <select id="pizzaSize">
                    <option name="e-small" data-price="4.99">Extra Small - £4.99</option>
                    <option name="small" data-price="5.99">Small - £5.99</option>
                    <option name="medium" data-price="6.99">Medium - £6.99</option>
                    <option name="large" data-price="8.99">Large - £8.99</option>
                    <option name="e-large" data-price="9.99">Extra Large - £9.99</option>
                    <option name="f-size" data-price="10.99">Family Size - £10.99</option>
                </select>
                </span>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset style = "border-top:0px">
        <form class="pure-form">
            <legend><b>Toppings (99p Each): &nbsp;</b></legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="onions">Onions</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="mushrooms">Mushrooms</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="peppers" >Peppers</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="olives" >Olives</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="garlic" >Garlic</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="peperoni" >Peperoni</input>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cheese" >Pesto</input>
        </form>
        </fieldset>
        <h2 style= "float:left; margin-top:-3cm; margin-left: 9cm; border: solid black 2px; padding: 5px"> £0.00 </h2>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="extraPizza"></div>
    <center><button id="addPizza"> Add Pizza </button></center>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("change","#pizzaSize", function() {
    var selectionPrice = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-price');
    var selectionInt = parseFloat(selectionPrice, 10);
    pizzaCost = selectionInt;
    $(this).closest('fieldset').nextAll('h2').first().text("£" + pizzaCost);
});

$( "#addPizza" ).click(function() {
  $("#pizzaForm").clone().appendTo("#extraPizza");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

h2 is inside your cloned element. So use `find()`.

```
$( "#addPizza" ).click(function() {

  var c=$("#pizzaForm").clone();  
  c.find("h2").html("");
  c.appendTo("#extraPizza");

});
```